# Correct usage of Crypto API in Linux

Tags: c, linux-kernel, cryptography

I am using the Crypto API (MD5) in the Linux kernel. It is "working" but I am not sure if it working correctly. As a test, I am using this string as an example:

```
Here is a completely different setup that should produce a different fingerprint. Let's see.
```

The resulting hash is

```
534d78034b774b6266f2189576f8c6e3
```

Seems legit. So I check an online site http://www.sha1-online.com/ to check their result

```
07a90df929448eb67b00a6e01a202519
```

Clearly wrong. Here is my code:

```
static int fingerprint(void)
{
  struct scatterlist sg;
  struct crypto_hash *tfm;
  struct hash_desc desc;
  unsigned char * output;
  unsigned char * buf;
  int i;

  output = kmalloc(sizeof(*output) * 16, GFP_KERNEL);
  memset(output, 0x00, 16);

  buf = "Here is a completely different setup that should produce a different fingerprint. Let's see.";

  tfm = crypto_alloc_hash("md5", 0, CRYPTO_ALG_ASYNC);

  desc.tfm = tfm;
  desc.flags = 0;

  sg_init_one(&sg, buf, 92);
  crypto_hash_init(&desc);

  crypto_hash_update(&desc, &sg, 92);
  crypto_hash_final(&desc, output);

  for(i = 0; i < 16; i++)
  {
    printk("%02x", output[i]);
  }

  printk("\n"); 
  return 0;
}
```

Is this code correct? Are there any problems (obvious or subtle) in it?

Comment: The hash you have shown is not the md5 hash of either of those strings as output by `md5sum`.

Comment: I am aware. It appears that after a certain input size, you get the same result.

Comment: That seems to be a misleading way of putting it - the hash shown is not an MD5 of the first string for any arbitrary truncation. Why do you tell the update function a size of 4096?  None of your inputs are that long.  (No, I don't know the Linux kernel crypto api)

Comment: When I passed the string in its array format (buf[]) is worked. I was under the impression that char buff[] and char * buff could be used interchangeably.